# Do Until specified value is reached in another cell

Tags: excel, vba, do-loops

I'd like to concatenate the number of days that add up to 80%. Please see the example below;

[image]

I can run a code that concatenates Range A1:A7 and the result is printed in C1;

```
Sub Concatenator()

Dim lastLng As Long
Dim result As String
Dim delim As String
Dim b As String

delim = "&"

lastLng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastLng

b = Cells(i, 1).Value
result = result & b & delim

Next

result = Left(result, Len(result) - Len(delim))

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 3).Value = result

End Sub
```

I'd to add a "Do Until" loop that loops until the value in column is greater than 80%. I've tried to amend the code above with the "Do Until" loop;

```
Sub Concatenator()

Dim lastLng As Long
Dim result As String
Dim delim As String
Dim b As String

delim = "&"

lastLng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

Do Until Cells(i, 2).Value = ">80%"

For i = 1 To lastLng1

b = Cells(i, 1).Value
result = result & b & delim

Next

Loop

result = Left(result, Len(result) - Len(delim))

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 3).Value = result

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand this might work for you
To understand how to set up the code, take a look [For-Loop](https://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/) and [Do-while](https://analystcave.com/vba-do-while-loop-using-do-while-vba/), then combine the conditions with the loop as the following code

```
i = 1
Do Until Cells(i, 2).Value = 0.8 'Loop until request condition
    If i > lastLng1 Then Exit Do 'Loop until end of the range
    b = Cells(i, 1).Value
    result = result & b & delim
    i = i + 1
Loop

'Or------------------------------

For i = 1 To lastLng1                        'Loop until end of the range
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = 0.8 Then Exit For 'Loop until request condition
    b = Cells(i, 1).Value
    result = result & b & delim
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, but it concatenates all the days. It's only supposed the concatenate Monday-Wednesday

Comment: The problem is that if the cell value is 80% it is a number `Cells(i, 2).Value = 0.8` or it is equal to the string `Cells(i, 2).Value = "80%"`

Comment: I changed the format to a number=80. Your code worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
Sub Concatenator()

Dim lastLng As Long
Dim result As String
Dim delim As String
Dim b As String

delim = "&"

lastLng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastLng
    If Cells(i, 2).Value > "80" Then Exit For
    b = Cells(i, 1).Value
    result = result & b & delim
Next

result = Left(result, Len(result) - Len(delim))

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 3).Value = result

End Sub
```

I changed the value in column be from a percentage to a number. I also removed the equal sign

```
For i = 1 To lastLng
    If Cells(i, 2).Value > "80" Then Exit For
    b = Cells(i, 1).Value
    result = result & b & delim
Next
```

This will work very well for me for now. Thank you @The GridLock